# Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, server, connection

I am trying to make a program in java the accepts any connection but I getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Thread

at ojas.gome.Server.<init>(Server.java:37)
at ojas.gome.Server.main(Server.java:12)
```

This piece of code gives me this error:

```
clientaccepter = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        server.accept();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, "clientaccepter").run();
```

Please tell me if I left out anything needed.

Comment: Don't call `run` at the end. You should never call it at all. Do `clientaccepter.start()` after that line to start the `Thread`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting a variable equal to the result of the `run` method which does not return a value - it's `void`.

`clientaccepter = new Thread....run();`

You should declare the thread and then start it on a separate line if you need to retain a reference to it. Also, you should use `start` to begin a new `Thread` not `run`. Please see [Defining and Starting a Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html). Lastly, variables should be camel case starting with lowercase - please see [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

```
clientAccepter = new Thread(...);
clientAccepter.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. either go for complete statement Thread t = new Thread( new Runnable () )
   and call t.run() or
2. create directly new Thread() (new Runnalbe()) on that call start()
   as follows :

   ```
   public class InterfaceDemo {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() 
       {
           @Override
           public void run() 
           {
               for(int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
                   System.out.println("run() : "+i);
               }
           }
       }).start();

           for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++) {
               System.out.println("main() : "+i);
           }
       }// main
   } // class
   ```